# What is this in my system tray?

Tags: notifications

Every so often, seemingly random, this notification appears in my notification bar, but not in the tray.

[image: That circle on the left]

The circles on the left in the notification bar. I have no clue what it's related to. There's no notification if I slide the tray down. It doesn't stay long, about the time I check for it in the notification tray, it's gone. I develop for my phone. Would anything on the development side of things trigger this weird notification?

It's a Samsung Galaxy S3 running CyanogenMod nightlies, specifically 10.1-20130405-NIGHTLY-d2spr which is Android 4.2.2.

EDIT:

I've noticed that this appears very consistently when I have [Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp) open. It does not appear to be a notification caused by that app, but instead appears to be that the app is somehow "muting" notifications that happen while it is open. Is there something in the API that allows for the silencing of notifications originating from other apps?

Comment: To make sure what we refer to: you're talking about the "gray dot" in the very left of your screenshot, right? The one on top of the blueish area?

Comment: Yes. The dim, gray, concentric circles on the left.

Comment: OK -- with your permission, I modified your screenshot to make that clear (the original is still linked when you click on the displayed image). Not that I have any idea what that might be, but being on the left side usually implies it comes from some (user-) app.

Comment: There must be some service running in the background - perhaps CM stats?

Comment: I've looked through some of CyanogenMod's GitHub pages, but I can't find the resource in either CMStats or CMUpdater. And thanks @Izzy, I didn't think there was much room for confusion.

Comment: Obviously there was :) And you're welcome! If you figure out yourself, don't forget to let us know (after you made us curious). Feel free to answer your own question, just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found it in the Android API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int)

A flag, SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE, can be passed to indicate that certain UI elements be put into a Low Profile and offer less of a distraction to the user. If I had a nexus device (really any device with soft buttons across the bottom) then I would also notice those buttons being replaces by the same dim circle I'm seeing in my navbar.

This has been available since 4.0 and is intended for book readers, games, and other immersive applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is the indicator for low priority notifications, for example from Google Now.

Comment: This is correct. I can assure you it's not something we have added in CM.

Comment: From what I've discovered, it's not the notifications that are set as low priority, but the currently running app. Google Now's "low priority" decides if a notification gets an icon in the tray or if there's any vibration or audio cue. They share a name but not functionality.